# PHP + Javascript - Read/Write Cookies

Tags: php, javascript, cookies

Is it possible to create a cookie with javascript and then read it with PHP? And What about the other way around?

Comment: Your bio is looking great!. Look I have copied it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can both set and read cookies on either side.

On the javascript side you'll need to parse the `document.cookie` variable, but there are plenty of libs to do that (jQuery has a plugin to do so).

Comment: Make sure that you understand the order of things. You obviously can't have php and javascript share a cookie on the same page load.

Answer (score 2):

There is a new parameter in the php "setcookie" function (from php 5.2.0) that you should be aware of: it is called "httponly". If set to true (by you), javascript won't be allowed to read the cookie's content. It helps prevent XSS attacks.
More info on: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php