# How do I get cookies to work?

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

The cookie set using setcookie appears fine both in Chrome and Firefox.
The cookie set using document.cookie (from form) appears by going back and re-entering the page in Chrome and doesn't appear at all in Firefox. What am I doing wrong here?

index.php

```
<?php
$value = "chocolate";
setcookie("anothercookie", $value, time() + (86400 * 30), '/');
?>

<html>
<body>

<form action="action.php" method="GET">
  Name: <input type="text" name="username" /><br /><br />
  Cookie: <input type="text" name="formCookie" /><br /><br />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script>
  var myJavascriptVar = document.querySelector('[name="formCookie"]').value;
  document.cookie = "myJavascriptVar = " + myJavascriptVar;
</script>  


</body>
</html>
```

action.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET["username"]))
{
  $user = $_GET["username"];
  echo $user;
  echo " is your username <br />";
}
else 
{
  $user = null;
  echo "no username supplied <br />";
}

if (isset($_COOKIE['myJavascriptVar'])) {
  echo "Cookie is " . $_COOKIE['myJavascriptVar'];
}

echo "<br />";

if (isset($_COOKIE['anothercookie'])) {
  echo "Another cookie is " . $_COOKIE['anothercookie'];
}

?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP + Javascript - Read/Write Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199568/php-javascript-read-write-cookies)

Comment: Not sure if it matters or not but [the documentation on document.cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) does seem to insist on not having spaces between `key=value`